# Countdown count with GMT time from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-countdown

I need to work on a countdown counter for a specific future date-time. I managed to use following counter http://www.blacktie.co/demo/counter/ and made some minor changes to it when i was almost done i noticed that this counter use local system date & when i change the system date it is reflected on the counter. How can this script be modified to so that it will take GMT date from server when it starts counter rather than local date.

So that every users irrespective of their location will see the exact date-time of even happening in India.

Fiddle example 
http://jsfiddle.net/635hf1je/1/

script

```
(function ($) {
    /**
     * Set your date here  (YEAR, MONTH (0 for January/11 for December), DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND)
     * according to the GMT+0 Timezone
     **/
    var launch = new Date(2014, 11, 04, 12, 00);
    /**
     * The script
     **/
    var message = $('#message');
    var days = $('#days');
    var hours = $('#hours');
    var minutes = $('#minutes');
    var seconds = $('#seconds');

    setDate();

    function setDate() {
        var now = new Date();
        if (launch < now) {
            days.html('<h1>0</H1><p>Day</p>');
            hours.html('<h1>0</h1><p>Hour</p>');
            minutes.html('<h1>0</h1><p>Minute</p>');
            seconds.html('<h1>0</h1><p>Second</p>');
            message.html('coming soon...');
        } else {
            var s = -now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 + (launch.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000;
            var d = Math.floor(s / 86400);
            days.html('<h1>' + d + '</h1><p>Day' + (d > 1 ? 's' : ''), '</p>');
            s -= d * 86400;

            var h = Math.floor(s / 3600);
            hours.html('<h1>' + h + '</h1><p>Hour' + (h > 1 ? 's' : ''), '</p>');
            s -= h * 3600;

            var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
            minutes.html('<h1>' + m + '</h1><p>Minute' + (m > 1 ? 's' : ''), '</p>');

            s = Math.floor(s - m * 60);
            seconds.html('<h1>' + s + '</h1><p>Second' + (s > 1 ? 's' : ''), '</p>');
            setTimeout(setDate, 1000);

            message.html('coming soon...');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/635hf1je/2/ ?

Just convert the Javascript Date object into UTC.

```
var t = new Date(); 
var now = new Date(t.getUTCFullYear(), t.getUTCMonth(), t.getUTCDate(),  t.getUTCHours(), t.getUTCMinutes(), t.getUTCSeconds());
```

in `setDate()` function.

Comment: Try converting the launch date similarly to UTC, before passing it to the function.

Comment: Count down should always show the correct time related to the event of place. IF i change date or time it it changes counter also or if i change timezone of my desktop it still show a different counter.

Comment: Let me try UTC option you have mentioned.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Okay. Any success?

Comment: I dont think it will make any difference `var launch = new Date(2014, 11, 5, 06, 00);var launch = new Date(2014, 11, 9, 06, 00);`

Comment: I think it should work and the behaviour you are getting is obvious. If you change the dates then obviously the timer is going to change. But if you are modifying the hours only then converting it to UTC should resolve it.

Comment: May be i am doing it wrong. but on the other side time difference can be up 27 hours which will even show the wrong days on the counter.. problem is even if i only take `var now = new Date(t.getUTCFullYear(), t.getUTCMonth(), t.getUTCDate(),  t.getUTCHours(), t.getUTCMinutes(), t.getUTCSeconds());` this also changes when i change system date or time so how it show the correct counter. I am bit lost if you can show me an example which is working would be great. http://jsfiddle.net/0sL58q65/

Answer (score 0):

You can use php for getting the server time:

```
var now = <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");// Format it as you need it ?>
```

Comment: this can be the last option if it is not possible to change it. I am currently looking for option where i can get datetime using some free API..